# "zsh: command not found: pub" while testing my code for exercism

Tags: flutter, android-sdk-2.3, dart

I want to test my coding exercise for exercism.io. On the Intellij IDEA and Android Studio when I try to type on terminal "$ pub get" and "$ pub run test". I get this error "zsh: command not found: pub or $". I've been stacking here for 2 days. What should I do?

My System: Mac OS Catalina version 10.15.3.
My Android SDK is located: Users/vortovor/Developer/flutter/bin/cache

in cache there is a file named "dart-sdk".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use the `pub` shipped with the Flutter version you're using as told on the [pub tool section of Dart documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd):

> **Flutter note:** If you’re using the Flutter SDK, don’t use the pub command directly. Instead use the flutter pub command, (...)

```sh
flutter pub get
# or
flutter pub test
```